# RCurl Authentication issue

Tags: r, rcurl

I am trying to use the RCurl package to authenticate using the https protocol.  I have found that if I just execute a curl command at the command line: "curl --netrc --cacert "url" I am able to retrieve the data I desire.

However, when using the RCurl library and setting the appropriate options (SSL.verifypeers = TRUE, capath, netrc = TRUE, netrc.file = "~/.netrc"), I am unable to authenticate.

I have noticed that the version of curl that RCurl uses is 7.19.7 and the version installed on my server is 7.39.

Does this mean that I should try to rebuild RCurl, trying to use this new version of libcurl?

Comment: Turning off SSL verification is extremely bad practice.

Comment: Right you are; I have edited the post to include the SSL.verifypeers parameter equal to TRUE.  I noticed while trying to figure out how to make this work that many others had set this parameter equal to FALSE when they had similar issues.  In my case this did not have any affect on my ability to connect (obvious in hindsight).  Much safer to leave it TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I was simply missing the httpauth = 1L option.  After setting this, my issue disappeared.